# Random variables in

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, self-learning

I am having trouble with this task, I feel like I'm doing something wrong but I dont know what:

Let $X_1, X_2 \cdots X_n $  $ n \geq 2 $  be independent Bernoulli Experiments.
With a not specified "hitrate" of $p$.

Further let $Y = \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} X_i $  and $Z = \sum^n_{i=0} X_i $.

Also let $k \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \land k \neq 0 \land k \neq n $

Now the actual question:

Express the event $\{ Z =k\} \cap \{Y = k-1\} $ and the event $\{ Z=k \} \cap \{Y =k \} $ with the random variables $ Y $ and $X_n$ without using $Z$ or $X_1, \cdots,  X_{n-1} $

---

IMO the first one is:

$$ P(Y=k-1) \cdot P(X_n = x)$$

and the second one should be:

$$ P(Y=k-1) / P(X_n = x) $$

Can someone please look over my reasoning and correct me if I'm wrong. This isnt homework and only preparation for an exam.

Comment: Just a remark : the question was to express an event (which is a set), and your answer is its probability (which is a real)

Comment: What is $X_0 $ in  $Y = \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} X_i$ and $Z = \sum^n_{i=0} X_i$?

Comment: @LKM sorry my bad, the sum begins at $1$

Comment: @charMD sorry, my bad I've gone one step too far, should I fix it or is it clear what is asked ?

Comment: I think the first one is $P(Y=k-1) \cdot P(X_n = 1)$, the second is $P(Y=k-1) \cdot P(X_n = 0)$.

Comment: @zython As you wish, it is not really a big problem